# inner product inequality from Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

The proof in Spivaks Calculus on Manifolds to the problem below begins by saying "equality clearly holds if $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent".  then they proceed with writing the proof by stating that if $x$ and $y$ are not linearly dependent then $\lambda y-x\neq 0$ , $\forall \lambda\in \mathbb{R}$.  I'm not sure why equality holds when $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent?

thanks in advance.

> If $x$, $y$ $\in \mathbb{R^n}$ then
>
> $$\bigg|\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_1\bigg|\leq|x|\cdot|y|$$; equality holds iff $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: If they are linearly dependent, then one of them is a multiple of the other.

Comment: I've expanded both sides and I got $|x_1y_1+...+x_ny_n|$ $\leq $ $\sqrt{x^2_{1}+...x^2_{n}}$ $ \cdot$ $ \sqrt{y^2_{1}+...y^2_{n}}$. I still don't see how them being linearly dependent makes them equal.

Comment: Because you didn't use what I said. Set $y = cx$ for some $c$

Comment: ah!  Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is $a{{}}$?

Comment: I shouldn't have added $a$ since it's only relevant for the later problems.  I'll edit

Answer (score 1):

As spivak writes, when mathematics is done right it's trivial...

LHS $=\lambda (x_1^2 +\dots +x_n^2)=$ RHS when  $x $ and  $y $ are dependent , or $y=\lambda x $...